# ComponentArt: Clear a cell in a grid if it is a certain DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, grid, componentart

I currently have a ComponentArt Grid, which has a column containing DateTime values. In the even that a certain date is used, we want to keep the cell empty.

Since DateTime is a struct it cannot be null or empty. So I am looking for a way to tell the grid to leave the cell blank if this certain date is bound to the grid.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you binding your DataSource to CA's grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a GridColumn you can set it to use a custom client template (or a server template if you need ASP.NET components).

You can have whatever logic you may need there to hide the cell value (You may not print it at all).

For server templates you can see an example [here](http://docs.componentart.com/default.aspx?content=ComponentArt.Web.UI.AJAX/Grid_Server_Templates.htm), examples on client templates are in the docs too.